# Flutter list function execute error management

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

in a flutter, I execute multiple functions on initState. Like this:-

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
    function4();
  }
```

in case the `function2()` has some errors it affects `function3(),function4()` also. How do we avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `try` in each functions to avoid getting stop incase of getting error:

```
void function1(){
    try {
      //put you code hear
    } catch (e) {
      print("e = $e");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one have any other option

Comment: sorry but only this come to my mind

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `try` & `catch` but, there is a way to write only at one place !

create a `extension` on `Function` to call it & absorb the error if any occures in it.

Here is a example:

```
import 'dart:developer';

void f1() => print('f1');

void f2() => throw 'STOP';

void f3() => print('f3');

extension FunctionUtils on Function {
  void callAndAbsorbError() {
    try {
      this.call();
    } catch (e, st) {
      log("Error in $this", error: e, stackTrace: st);
    }
  }
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  f1.callAndAbsorbError();
  f2.callAndAbsorbError();
  f3.callAndAbsorbError();
}
```

This way you don't need to write try catch in every function you create. AND all your functions will execute for sure.

More about `extensions` : [vandad's blog](https://vandad.sh/dart-extensions/)